# How to amplify DC voltage using Op-Amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, 741-opamp

In some real-application, a certain module is used, and the output voltage from this module is from 5 to 10 v. The required voltage should be scaled to 10, i.e. the 10v yields a 12v, 5v yields a 6v, and so on.

All these details are not important, that's why I don't want to mention the application or the module.

The problem in brief is amplifying a DC voltage that has a single value from 5 to 10 volts to another DC voltage that has a maximum of 12 volts.

By measuring the output of the module at the high state, it gives exactly 9.15v, so to convert this 9.15v to 12v, I need to multiply the 9.15v by 12/9.15, which is 1.31; so, I designed the circuit below, which is a non-inverting amplifying circuit using LM741 Op-Amp. The gain is calculated as 1+R10/R9, where R9, and R10 are the resistors shown in the image below. So, R10/R9 = 0.31, please remember this ratio.

[image: 1]

Multisim's simulation gives exactly what I am looking for, I chose R10 to be 330 and R9 to be 1k so the ratio is 0.33 (approximately equal to 0.31 as actual resistors have not exact values, there is always a tolerance, which will make the ratio more closer to the required ratio).

Now, I implemented the shown circuit with hardware components, exactly the same as shown in the image, the power supply I used give exactly 12v, I connected the +ve terminal of the power supply to the pin 7 of LM741, and the -ve terminal of the power supply to the pin 4. Measured the voltage between pin 7 and 4 using multimeter, it was 12.07v (almost 12v). Then, connected the resistors in the proper way, and measured the output from pin 6, it was about 10.6v. So, I tried so many resistors that will give the same ratio (0.31 to 0.33), but I couldn't even have an 11v output. The maximum voltage I could get is 10.75, there is 1.25v that are significant for my application, and this about 10% of the whole 12v, so it cannot be neglected.

My question is why this behavior happens, why I cannot get the 12v exactly or even 11.5v using the circuit shown below.

Is the problem with the Op-Amp I am using? and If this is the case, what is the best Op-Amp among the Op-Amps below that I can use instead of LM741? Op-Amps available at the store I am buying from are: LF356, LM1458, LM311P, LM318, LM339N, LM358N, LM380N, NE5532, NE5534, TL071CN, TL074CN, TL082CP, UA741CN.

Final note: all components were working, i.e. resistors, Op-Amp, and power supply are all working nothing was damaged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use 15V supply and add a connection between pin 4 of OpAmp and GND

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the other answers which explain that your power supply is insufficient to give you 12V output using a non-rail-to-rail op amp like the obsolete 741, it has also been pointed out to you that you cannot leave your power supply floating relative to the op-amp. You need a ground. Some op-amps are configured with split or "bipolar" supplies, like +/- 15V. Others are configured to have low rail grounded. But you have done neither according to your schematic. Go back and read the answers and comments from your previous question.

Here is an example of using a split supply to power an op amp. It is from an answer to your previous question.

[image]

Comment: @M-125 I added a schematic from an answer to your previous question that shows how a split supply works. Notice that the ground and the supply are interconnected. It is possible in some cases to use a single rail supply with op amps. Not all cases. For a single rail supply, just connect the negative power pin to ground. That is remove the voltage supply symbol that connects to the op amp's negative supply pin. Leave the other voltage source as it appears in the schematic.

Comment: Well, it won't fix your problem, because even if you properly ground the power supply, you still cannot get a non-rail-to-rail op-amp like the 741 to output 12V if it is only supplied 12V. However, given that your power supply lacks an interconnection with ground, it is something of a matter of luck that your circuit even comes close to working correctly.

Comment: @M-125 If you the price of a power supply to a single 741 price, you should try to operate an op amp without any supply at all. If you have a bipolar input signal and need a bipolar output signal and you need 10 or more op amps, the circuit is much easier when using a bipolar supply.

Comment: @M-125 the name "bipolar supply" may be confusing. It means a "split" supply, or a supply that has three outputs, V+, V-, and Ground.

Comment: Ask that as a separate question, because comments are not really for tutorials. It is actually a good question in my humble opinion.

Comment: The choice of op-amp depends on what you are trying to do. None of the op-amps you have available are rail-to,-rail as far as I know, although the TL 082 might get you close (within a volt). If your only requirement is to get a 12V output using a 12V supply,  I don't think any of them will succeed fully.

Answer (score 4):

You are asking an op amp to output 12 volts when its supply voltage is also 12 volts. This is not possible, especially with an op amp like the 741 which has a maximum output of several volts less than its supply voltage. You might have a chance if you increase the supply voltage to 15 volts. Other op amps can reach an output voltage closer to the supply voltage than the 741 but none can have an output equal to the supply voltage. Look at the data sheets for some of the op amps that you listed especially at the maximum output voltage.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the datasheet, it says the maximum output voltage of the 741 is about 1.5v or 2.0V LESS than the supply voltage. So, although you used the proper gain, you didn't account for another limitation of this op amp and its 57-year-old design.